# assigning textbox value to a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
 Dim loc As String = ""
    If txtlocated.Value <> "ABC" Then
        loc = txtlocated.Value
```

txtlocated is the id of the HTML textbox. I want to assign the value of the textbox to the string loc. When i debug it the loc is shown as null the textbox value is not passed into the string. Any suggestions what is wrong in the code.

Thanks,

Comment: You should do loc = txtlocated.Text and i think this Language is VB

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Does `txtlocated.Value` return the correct value?

Comment: yes txtlocated.value returns the correct value but that is not passed to loc. I don't know why

Comment: can you do a ToString() operation? i.e. loc = txtlocated.Value.ToString();

Comment: i changed the input type to asp textbox but still i can't the textbox value in loc. I tried the loc=txtlocated.Value.ToString() but still i can't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim text As String = Request("txtlocated")

Dim loc As String = "" 
If text <> "ABC" Then
     loc = text 
End If
```

Comment: i tried your method. I am getting the value in text but loc is empty

Comment: @asifa You're getting the value in text?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this to:

```
Dim loc As String = ""
If txtlocated.Text <> "ABC" Then
    loc = txtlocated.Text
End If
```

Note I'm using `Text`, not `Value`.

Comment: I m getting Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText

Comment: Right, I assumed you were using an ASP.NET TextBox. Are you able to change the control from an <input> to an <asp:Textbox>?

Comment: no i can't change it because that will create problem in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but give it a try:

```
loc=string.Format("{0}",Request.Form["txtlocated"]);
```

Comment: OP has stated in my comments that they are using a HTML textbox. Text is not a member of this control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with VB ( I am C# guy). But HtmlControls require you to use Form.Request

in C#

```
string loc = Form.Request["controlid"];
```